# Programatically calling PopoverPresentationController from a custom class which is not a viewcontroller

Tags: swift, ios8

I am trying to present a popoverpresentationcontroller from a custom class which is not a viewcontroller, but that doesnt seem to work. I have only one viewcontroller apart from the viewcontroller I created for the popover. And I want to achieve this programatically. Any ideas?

Here is my sample code:

```
func showErrorPopup() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let parentViewController =    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    if let contentView  = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ErrorPopUpView") as? ErrorViewController {
        contentView.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        contentView.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400.0, 500.0)
        if let _popoverPresentationController = contentView.popoverPresentationController {
            _popoverPresentationController.delegate = self
            _popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
            _popoverPresentationController.sourceView = parentViewController?.view
            _popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(-30, -280, 320, 400)
            parentViewController?.presentViewController(contentView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Create a delegate in the non-viewcontroller that references the view controller.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRiselvato it worked well. Just a note we tried observer and notification as well which worked but we are leaning towards delegate pattern. Thanks for your response.

Comment: did you try UIApplication.sharedApplication().rootViewController  for handling presentation?